# How to add values from two different columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to add first rows from two different columns of a dataframe together, such that if column A's first row is `NaN`, replace with value from `balance`'s first row, otherwise, add column A's first row and `balance`'s first row. And so likewise column B. The idea is using `balnce` first row to transform first row of other columns' A and B.
I attempted using `df.iloc[0]` to get the first row but I'm unable to set the value or add it:

```
data = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        'A': [None, None, 20, 10, 39, 30],
        'B': [13, 98, 23, 45, 64, 10],
        'balance': [23, 41, 12, 22, 32, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('id')
print df

    A   B    balance
id                 
1  NaN  13   23
2  NaN  98   41
3   20  23   12
4   10  45   22
5   39  64   32
6   30  10   0

for i in df.columns:
    if i not in ['balance']:
        if df[i].iloc[0] == None:
            df[i].iloc[0] = df['balance'].iloc[0]
        else:
            df[i].iloc[0] = df[i].iloc[0] + df['balance'].iloc[0]

        print df[i]


id
1   NaN
2   NaN
3    20
4    10
5    39
6    30
Name: A, dtype: float64


id
1    36
2    98
3    23
4    45
5    64
6    10
Name: B, dtype: int64
#A[0] should be 23, and B[0] should be 13 + 23 = 36
```

desired output:

```
id  A   B     balance               
1   23  36       23
2  NaN  98       41
3   20  23       12
4   10  45       22
5   39  64       32
6   30  10        0
```

Comment: Only the first row?

Comment: Your prose explanation doesn't match your sample code. You are setting *A* to *balance* when *A* is empty.

Comment: What is desired output? Column balance?

Comment: @ayhan yes, only the first row

Comment: @jezrael my bad - I made corrections to the post. The idea is to use `balance` to transform the first rows of columns A and B. If the columns are `NaN`, replace both A and B with `balance`. If otherwise: balance + A`, `balance + B`. This is only for the first rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) if need replace `NaN` by values of other column:

```
print (df.A.combine_first(df.B))
id
1    13.0
2    98.0
3    20.0
4    10.0
5    39.0
6    30.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Or:

```
print (df.A.fillna(df.B))
id
1    13.0
2    98.0
3    20.0
4    10.0
5    39.0
6    30.0
Name: A, dtype: float64


print (df.A.combine_first(df.B) + df.B)
id
1     26.0
2    196.0
3     43.0
4     55.0
5    103.0
6     40.0
dtype: float64
```

If need sum two columns with replacing `NaN` to `0` use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) with parameter `fill_value`:

```
print (df.A.add(df.B, fill_value=0))
id
1     13.0
2     98.0
3     43.0
4     55.0
5    103.0
6     40.0
dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

You need:

```
df.ix[1,'A'] = df.ix[1,'balance']
print (df)
       A   B  balance
id                   
1   23.0  13       23
2    NaN  98       41
3   20.0  23       12
4   10.0  45       22
5   39.0  64       32
6   30.0  10        0
```

EDIT1:

```
df.ix[1,'A'] = df.ix[1,'balance']
df.ix[1,'B'] = df.ix[1,'B'] + df.ix[1,'balance']

print (df)
       A   B  balance
id                   
1   23.0  36       23
2    NaN  98       41
3   20.0  23       12
4   10.0  45       22
5   39.0  64       32
6   30.0  10        0
```

Comment: OP states that "A[0] should be 23".

Comment: My solution is only guessing, if output is bad or all is bad, I remove it.

Comment: OP's wording of question is poor. Assuming the bottom comment in their code "A[0] should be 23, and B[0] should be 13 + 23 = 36"  correctly describes what they want, I think using `df.A.fillna(0)` would provide the desired answer. Question needs to be better articulated.

Comment: @Grr - thank you for comment - I am not sure what OP exactly want too.

Comment: @jezrael, only teh first row gets transformed. I included the desired output

Comment: @jezrael sorry, I was expecting `B` to also transform to `36`. i.e. `23` + `13`

Comment: @KrugerBr - sorry, I think it works nice, so you accept solution - so now edit answer to your desired output. Please check it.